# What are the airflow patterns of a helicopter when operating in ground effect?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter, ground-effect

When operating in the air cushion region of approximately 8 inches and below to the ground what pattern does the downward flow of air flow?

Answer (score 4):

What happens at a height of 8 inches and below in the hover in ground effect is a function of rotor diameter: everything is relative. Ground effect becomes noticeable at about one rotor diameter from the ground surface, so if your rotor is 8 inches in diameter there is not yet a significant change of the downward air flow.

[image]

If we limit ourselves to discussions of flow as a function of rotor diameter, we can see the following happen as illustrated in the above figure, from J. Gordon Leishman, Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics:

- Out of Ground Effect, the ground has little or no effect on the rotor outflow. The spiralling lines in the figure are the blade tip vortices.
- In Ground Effect, the rotor downwash appears compressed and spread out. One way of understanding how ground effect affects lift, is by considering that the static pressure underneath is increased and contributes to the lift.

The spiralling blade tip vortices are compressed and spread out as well, and this has a large effect on wake fluctuations, particularly noticeable for a ground observer. What exactly happens regarding spiralling gusts is not yet fully understood - from Prouty, Helicopter Performance, Stability and Control, page 68:

> The wake in ground effect is not really a steady flow..., but a flow with large scale fluctuations that can be felt as gusts by an observer standing near the helicopter. Reference 1.21 speculates that these fluctuations are associated with the vortex that is made up of the individual vortices from the blade roots.This vortex apparently writhes like a pinned snake along the ground, causing the entire wake to shift and wobble.
>
> Pilots occasionally report that when hovering in ground effect, they experience random yaw disturbances. This is probably due  to the effect of the root vortex as it writhes near the tail rotor.

Comment: Thanks for the input Koyovis! I had heard that many people speculate that the pattern of the downwash takes on a horseshoe pattern have you heard anything on that?

Comment: No I have never seen a reference to horseshoe shaped downwash.

Comment: I was going to fix this sentence, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to be: `and this has a large effect on was fluctuations` Is **was** supposed to be **wake**?

Comment: Thanks @TomMcW, sometimes autocorrect makes weird autocorrections. The original *splelling* mistake was of course mine.

Comment: Well, once the rotor is moving in one direction of course will a horseshoe vortex result, like with a wing. Only with a more complex flow pattern.

Comment: Koyovis you commented on a similar question that I posted, “How to keep a helicopter steady when close to the ground,” and mentioned how people would feel large fluctuations of air when standing next to the helicopter. That example coupled with how the root vortices cause random yaw movements for pilots makes perfect sense. My question is whether or not we can anticipate these movements to counter them?

Comment: @Wes According to the description from Prouty the disturbances are of a random nature, which would imply that timing and magnitude cannot be anticipated. I could not find any frequency distribution plots of the rotor down wake affecting the vertical tail - it could be that some of the vortex effects are of a periodic nature because of the blade passing frequency, but I could not confirm this.

Comment: @koyovis I greatly appreciate taking the time to look for the answer to my question! Unfortunately like you stated, these disturbances cannot be anticipated but I would like to think as you do that there would be some what of a consistent pattern due to  the vortex effects of the blade passing frequency.